# Dividing the array and subtracting array elements from each block: C program

Tags: c

I have an array having 100 numbers say a[1,2,3,4,5,6....98,99,100]. I want to divide it into 25 groups with each group containing 4 elements and then subtract elements of other blocks with each element of one block. For example: if three blocks out of 25 are labelled as A,B,C and contain elements as:

```
A [1,2,3,4], 
B[5,6,7,8] &
C[9,10,11,12]
```

then subtraction is to be done like this:

```
(A-B, A-C),
(B-A, B-C) & 
(C-A, C-B)
```

i.e.

```
1-5,1-6,1-7,1-8,1-9,1-10,1-11,1-12; then 
2-5,2-6,2-6,2-8,2-9,2-10,2-11,2-12; then 
3-5,3-6,3-7,3-8,3-9,3-10,3-11,3-12; then 
4-5,4-6,4-7,4-8,4-9,4-10,4-11,4-12;
```

THEN 
    5-1,5-2,5-3,5-4,5-9,5-10,5-11,5-12; 
and like wise..

Can anyone help me in writing C program for this.
The code that I have written is partial and not doing the above task completely. Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
  int a[100]={1,2,3,4.....,98,99,100};
  int i=0, j=0;
  int x[100], y[100];
  // considering only 12 numbers for the sake of simplicity
  for (i=0;i<12;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
      x[j] = a[i] - a[r+4];
    }
    y[i] = x[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Tell us what you've done so far.

Comment: we don't write programs for people' have no own attempt

Comment: The requirement/algorithm is unclear anyway:(

Comment: Use code tag, good indent help to make your code readable.

Comment: Hello A.B., we don't write full code here. Please decide on one language, try to solve the problem yourself and come back showing your code when you get stuck.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int N, i;
    scanf("%d", &N);

    int numArray[N]; // Define an array of four integers

    // Get inputs for the array elements
    for (i=0;i<N; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &numArray[i]);
    }

    int sum = 0;
    // Write here the logic to add these integers:
    for (i=0;i<N;i++) sum += numArray[i];



    printf("%d\n",sum);  // Print the sum

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, you answered a question that should be closed because it is off-topic for this site. This might lead to downvotes and encourages users to ask off-topic questions. Please flag off-topic questions instead.